# Failure to display software icons and text in Debian

Tags: debian, icons

in Debian, which is installed on VirtualBox, when I install the software, the icons and texts are not displayed, like the attachment photo.
What should I do to fix this problem?

Mouse clicking around in that area where they should be typically causes them to eventually appear